# Reading data from Oracle DB in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to read/write data from my Oracle DB into my iPhone code.
Can you suggest some methods for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is provide your iOS App a [REST Api](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and implement methods to read/update/delete your model entities.

If you could access a database directly from your iOS App, for every change in your model you had to deploy a new version on your iOS App. Providing a REST Api you can made changes in your model and do not change parameters or response on your services.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..Do u know of any ways to create REST API's for the Oracle DB?

Comment: You have to implement your own in any programming language: Java, Python, Ruby, PHP... You can check the next link that will help you to implement your REST Api in PHP. But you can choose any other :) http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Database connections generally expect to be reliable.  Connections from an iPhone aren't.

Also, any DB administrator would tell you that the first step to ensuring database security is to lock down the number of places from which the database can be directly accessed.  This is why you never (or *should* never) see client devices talking directly to a database.

Instead, implement an intermediary (such as a web service) that accepts, e.g., HTTPS connections from the iPhone in the usual manner (`NSURLConnection`, etc.) and does the actual database heavy lifting itself.  I'm not an Oracle expert, but I would assume that they have some products that help you do this with relatively little effort given how common a task it is.  If not, it should be fairly straightforward for you to implement your own in Java, Python, or a language of your choosing.